# Custom Labels and tests

Tags: apex, unit-test, customlabel

Can I access the value of a custom label during an Apex test?  Do I have to use "SeeAllData=true" to get the value? If so, what value do I get back when not using "SeeAllData=true"?

The documentation is silent on these points.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_about.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Custom labels should be accessable during test methods just like custom fields, etc are. I would think a great way to confirm this would be to try it out.

Comment: I will certainly be doing so.  I have hopes that someone already knows the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just tested, Test class can access custom label. No need to enable seeAllDate=true.

Answer (score 4):

Custom labels should be accessable during test methods just like custom fields, etc are. I would think a great way to confirm this would be to try it out

This will take 1 minute to test:

```
@isTest
private class testLabel{

     private static testmethod void basicTest(){
        String testLbl = Label.<custom label name>;
        system.debug(logginglevel.error,testLbl);

     }

}
```

I would but I am not able to get in an org at the moment.